# How to add arrow to current page navigation link items?

Tags: html, css

Like this. With IE6 compatibility too.

[image]

```
<ul>
<li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
<li class="selected"><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
<li><a href="/contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="/portfolio/">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="/gallery/">Gallery</a></li>
<ul>​
```

You can use this jsfiddle example to play with

http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/GN6ed/

and this arrow image https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGoLj.gif

Comment: If you want IE6 support, you'll need another element, and probably images...

Comment: I'm curious to know what requires ie6 support today. Pretty much everywhere else but China ie6 is less than 4%. A simple "update your browser" type of message is what I usually do these days with maybe a chrome frame test.

Comment: @elclanrs - It depends on analytic. the sites I'm working upon still getting 20% traffic from IE6. according to GA report

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS3's transform property to rotate a small box to 45 Deg, and make it look like an arrow.

```
.arrow {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);  /* FF3.5+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);  /* IE9 */
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);  /* Opera 10.5 */
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(/* IE6–IE9 */
    M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476, sizingMethod='auto expand');
    zoom: 1;
}
```

#### Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/GN6ed/3/)

#### Update 2: Here is the [PURE CSS SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/GN6ed/5/) with the border too.

Comment: it's good but not like I want. see my example image. I need only red border for arrow

Answer (score 1):

This wouldn't be easy to accomplish in IE6.

You could use something like this. But it wouldn't be supported in IE6 as it doesn't support the ::before pseudo class.

```
.selected {
   position:relative;
}

.selected::before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 42%;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 7px solid transparent;
border-right: 7px solid transparent;
border-top: 13px solid red;
}​
```

If you decide to do this with just css take a look at this http://www.robjstanley.com/css3-shapes/.

There's a speech bubble shape that you can do with just css3, pretty cool.

Comment: ok but i want to give colour to only to border. see my example image

Answer (score 1):

I didn't tested it on IE6 but i am sure it's work on it.

Check this  http://jsfiddle.net/GN6ed/4/

Answer (score 0):

Simple CSS will do the trick:

```css
.selected a {background:white; 
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/QHFqq.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 0%;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GN6ed/1/).

Dunno about IE6 can't test it here but I think this is as cross browser as possible, using basic CSS stuff.

Comment: no i want arrow at bottom and when i set it to bottom. it goes under the boundary of <a>

Comment: To place the image outside the element you can't use pure CSS - you will have to use client side scripting. If still relevant let me know and I'll throw some quick example.